# Integral of exponential function over an $n-1$ - simplex

Tags: integration, fourier-transform, gamma-function, poisson-distribution, simplex

I am trying to solve the following integral over the simplex (I'm not sure if there even is a closed form to be honest)

$$
\int_{\Delta^{n-1}}\prod\limits_{i = 1}^n x_{i}^{a_i}e^{-b_ix_i}dx_i
$$

Where $a_i, b_i \in \mathbb{R}$, $a_i > -1, b_i \geq 0$, $x_i \in \left[0,1\right]$, and $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i = 1$.

My first plan of attack was to rewrite this integral as

$$
\int\limits_0^1\int\limits_0^{1-x_{1}}\cdots\int\limits_0^{1-\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1} x_i}\prod\limits_{i = 1}^n x_{i}^{a_i}e^{-b_ix_i}dx_i
$$
$$
= \int\limits_0^1\int\limits_0^1\cdots\int\limits_0^1\delta\left(1-\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1} x_i\right)\prod\limits_{i = 1}^n x_{i}^{a_i}e^{-b_ix_i}dx_i
$$
where I use the delta function to enforce the simplex. This allows me to use this definition of the delta function
$$
\delta\left(1-\sum\limits_{ i=1}^{n-1} x_i\right) = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-2\pi i\left(1-\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1} x_i\right)k}dk
$$

And now I have a separable integral that looks like this
$$
\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int\limits_0^1\int\limits_0^1\cdots\int\limits_0^1e^{-2\pi i\left(1-\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1} x_i\right)k}\prod\limits_{i = 1}^n x_{i}^{a_i}e^{-b_ix_i}dx_ idk
$$
Now, I tried to start with the one-dimensional case, which should look like this
$$
\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int\limits_0^1 x^{a}e^{-bx}e^{-2\pi i \left(1-x\right)k}dx dk
$$

but doing the $x$ integral first gives me
$$
\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int\limits_0^1 x^{a}e^{-bx}e^{-2\pi i \left(1-x\right)k}dx dk = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\gamma\left(a-1, 1\right)}{\left(b+2\pi ik\right)^{a-1}}e^{-2\pi ik}dk \tag{1}
$$
where $\gamma\left(s,u\right)$ is the lower incomplete gamma function. This integral is also equivalent to (assuming the unit step function $H(0) = 1$)
$$
\int\limits_0^1 \delta\left(1-x\right)x^{a}e^{-bx}dx = e^{-b} \tag{2}
$$

The integral in $(1)$ is rather complicated and I don't know how to do it to get the result in $(2)$. Moreover, when I generalize to the $n-$dimensional case, I would have a product of these incomplete gamma functions in the integral which I don't really know how to work with.

Is this maybe the wrong approach to this integral? Does this integral over the simplex even have a closed form?

For context, this integral comes from putting a Dirichlet prior on $x_i$ for a product of Poisson distributions with mean $b_ix_i$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Gérard Letac, we are looking at the Laplace transform of a Dirichlet distribution of parameter $\alpha=(\alpha_1,\dotsc,\alpha_n)$ where $\alpha_i=a_i+1$ (and the $a_i$'s are those in the question), computed at a point $b=(b_1,\dotsc, b_n)$.

The Fourier (hence the Laplace) transform $\widehat{D_\alpha}(\mathbb{i}b)$ of the Dirichlet distribution
$$\widehat{D_\alpha}(s):= \int_{\Delta^{n-1}} \prod_{i=1}^n x_i^{\alpha_i-1} e^{\mathbb{i}\, s_i x_i} {\rm d}x_i, \qquad s=(s_1,\dotsc,s_n)\in\mathbb R^n,$$
is known in several equivalent formulations.
It will be convenient to distinguish vectors from scalars, so vectors are from now on denoted by bold-face letters. $\mathbb{i}$ is the imaginary unit.

1. **contracted (contour) integral representation**$\quad$
   Let $B(a,b)$ be the [Euler beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function).
   Let $${}_nF_D[a,\mathbf{b},c,\mathbf{s}]:=\frac{1}{B(a,c-a)}\int_0^1 t^{a-1}(1-t)^{c-a-1} \prod_{i=1}^n (1-ts_i)^{-b_i}{\rm d}t, \qquad \Re(c)>\Re(a)>0,$$
   be the integral representation of the $n$-variate hypergeometric Lauricella function of type $D$.
   The (first) *confluent form* of ${}_nF_D$ is the *second Kummer function*
   $${}_n\Phi_2[\mathbf b;c;\mathbf s]:= \lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+} {}_kF_D[\epsilon^{-1};\mathbf b; c, \epsilon\, \mathbf s].$$

Then,
$$\widehat{D_{\boldsymbol\alpha}}(\mathbf s)= {}_n\Phi_2[\boldsymbol\alpha;\alpha_1+\cdots+\alpha_n;\mathbb{i}\mathbf{s}].$$

2. **hypergeometric series representation** $\quad$ The second Kummer function also has a representation as hypergeometric series in terms of the Pochhammer symbol $\langle \alpha \rangle_n:=\alpha(\alpha+1)(\alpha+2)\cdots (\alpha+n-1)$, and we have

$$\widehat{D_{\boldsymbol\alpha}}(\mathbf s)= \sum_{\mathbf m\in \mathbb N_0^n} \frac{\langle\alpha_1\rangle_{m_1}\cdots \langle\alpha_n\rangle_{m_n}}{m_1!\cdots m_n!} \frac{\mathbb i^{m_1+\cdots+m_n} s_1^{m_1}\cdots s_n^{m_n}}{\langle \alpha_1+\cdots+\alpha_n\rangle_{m_1+\cdots+m_n}}.$$

3. **representation as exponential generating function of cycle index polynomials** $\quad$
   Finally, the second Kummer function can also be expressed (and this is probably the most meaningful form) as the exponential generating function of (renormalized) cycle index polynomials of symmetric groups.
   Let $Z_k$ be the [cycle index polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_index#Symmetric_group_Sn) of the symmetric group acting on $k$ elements. Then,
   $$\widehat{D_{\boldsymbol\alpha}}(-\mathbb{i}\, t\, \mathbf s)={}_n\Phi_2[\boldsymbol\alpha; \alpha_1+\cdots+\alpha_n;t\mathbf{s}]= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{t^k}{\langle\alpha_1+\cdots+\alpha_n\rangle_k} Z_k(\mathbf s^{\circ 1}\cdot\boldsymbol\alpha,\mathbf s^{\circ 2}\cdot\boldsymbol\alpha,\cdots, \mathbf s^{\circ k}\cdot\boldsymbol\alpha)$$
   where
   $$\mathbf s^{\circ i} \cdot \boldsymbol\alpha:= \alpha_1s_1^i+\cdots +\alpha_n s_n^i$$ is the scalar product between $\boldsymbol\alpha$ and the $i$-th [entry-by-entry (Hadamard) power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)) of $\mathbf s$ and the explicit expression for $Z_k$ is
   $$Z_k[a_1,\cdots,a_k]= \sum_{j_1+2 j_2 + 3 j_3 + \cdots + k j_k = k} \frac{1}{\prod_{h=1}^k h^{j_h} j_h!} \prod_{h=1}^k a_h^{j_h}.$$

References and proofs for all the above statements can be found [here](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/electronic-journal-of-probability/volume-24/issue-none/Characteristic-functionals-of-Dirichlet-measures/10.1214/19-EJP371.full) (open access).

**Remark** Depending on the purpose of the computation, some of the above representations are more useful than others. The formulation in 3. is especially useful if you need $n\gg 1$. (Actually, this is seen already when $n\geq 2$.)

**Remark** Using the fact that the exponential generating function of the cycle index polynomials (this time non-renormalized) is an exponential (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_index#Symmetric_group_Sn)), it might be possible to show that no closed form exists for the Fourier transform of the Dirichlet distribution (i.e. ${}_k\Phi_2$ is in general not resummable to a composition of elementary functions)

Answer (score 0):

Why looking for the Laplace transform of a Dirichlet distribution, while even in dimension $n=2$ this is not elementary and are called the Kummer special functions? Laplace transforms are good for addition of independent random variables: and  who cares for adding something concentrated on a tetraedron?

In the other hand, Dirichlet distributions have their moments quite easy to compute. Let me mention also the following integral, with the notations $x_n=1-x_1-\cdots-x_{n-1}$ and $a=a_1+\cdots+a_n$ $$\frac{\Gamma(a)}{\Gamma(a_1)\cdots \Gamma(a_n))}\int_{x_i>0, i=1,\ldots,n}\frac{x_1^{a_1-1}\cdots x_n^{a_n-1}}{(b_1x_1+\cdots+b_nx_n)^a}dx_1\ldots dx_{n-1}=\frac{1}{b_1^{a_1}\ldots b_n^{a_n}}.$$ Here we assume $a_1,\ldots, a_n,b_1,\ldots,b_n>0$

This post should have been in comments, rather than answers, but it was a bit too long. Hoping it will be useful anyway.

Comment: The motivation for introducing the Fourier transform definition of the delta function was to decouple the $x_i$ integrals which would otherwise have rather complicated bounds imposed by the simplex. The delta function allows me to do the integral w.r.t. to $x_i$ from $0$ to $1$ directly and obtain the result I have in $(1)$.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the one-dimensional integral in is as follows:

\begin{align*}
\int_0^1 x^a e^{-bx} e^{-2\pi i (1-x) k} dx &= \frac{\gamma(a + 1, b + 2\pi i k)}{b + 2\pi i k}
\end{align*}
where γ(a,x) is the incomplete gamma function.

This solution can be derived using a series expansion of the incomplete gamma function.

It is important to note that this solution is only valid if the incomplete gamma function is invertible.